# How can I get my fingerprint reader to work alongisde my password?

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, authentication, fingerprint

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430 with an integrated fingerprint reader. I want to make it work alongside my password, not replace it. What I mean by this is that, when a password prompt comes up, I want to be able to type my password right there, or, alternatively, use the fingerprint reader without any extra input.

I managed to make the reader work with fprint. I configured all my fingers and added the corresponding lines to the corresponding config files, and as it is right now, anytime the system needs a root password, it prompts me for my finger first, if it fails three times it then gives me a password prompt. Also, on my login screen, I can't use the reader until I have pressed enter on the empty password prompt first.

I guess I should detail more about my login screen and distro. I use lightdm with the webkit2-greeter and a custom theme for that greeter called Aether. The OS is Linux Mint 20 with the Cinnamon desktop. As I said, I can't use the reader until I pressed enter on the empty field, I then can login with it no issues. I would rather have the option to login with my reader without any extra input. These are my config files:

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    sufficient  pam_fprintd.so                      <-- RELEVANT LINE
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    sufficient  pam_fprintd.so      <-- RELEVANT LINE
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
#session required        pam_loginuid.so
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

`/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    sufficient  pam_fprintd.so         <-- RELEVANT LINE
auth    required        pam_permit.so
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Added OS and DE (Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon)

Comment: From the code I assume you are using Linux, Please specify in your question what distribution and version you use. Maybe you are looking for instructions like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en

Comment: Noted, I added that, thanks.

Comment: @Bodo - Do the instructions you linked show how to enable any of both unlocking methods *at the same time*?